# Removing single pixel row from image in Python 3 with PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Is there any simple way to remove a single row of pixels in PIL (Pillow)?

[image: removing pixel row]

I have considered

- Splitting the image into two copies
- Cropping the copies, +1 row in one of them
- Combining the copies together

But it seems unnecessary complicated.

I am not familiar with modifying images in other python libraries, but if it is significantly simplyfying the task I will consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the image into a [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) array using `numpy.array(image)` and then use `numpy.delete()` to remove a row before converting it back into an image with `PIL.Image.fromarray()`.

For example, this would remove the 7th row from the image.

```
a = numpy.array(im)

a = numpy.delete(a, 6, 0)

im = Image.fromarray(a)
```